# SQL Server 2014 LocalDB stopped working after ReportViewer 2015 Runtime installation

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I was able to connect to `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` without any issues. I then installed Microsoft ReportViewer 2015 runtime, and can no longer connect.

The error I get is:

> Cannot connect to (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB.
>
> Additional information:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occured.
>   Error occured during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process
>   failed to start.) (Microsoft SQL Server)

Has anyone come across this before, and know how to fix it? I can't find anything on it :\

The event log has the following;

> Windows API call WaitForMultipleObjects returned error code: 575.
>   Windows system error message is: {Application Error} The application
>   was unable to start correctly (0x%lx). Click OK to close the
>   application. Reported at line: 3728.

The SQL Server log has the following:

```
{Date} {Time} Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64) 
    Apr 20 2015 17:29:27 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

{Date} {Time} Server      UTC adjustment: 10:30
{Date} {Time} Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
{Date} {Time} Server      All rights reserved.
{Date} {Time} Server      Server process ID is 4392.
{Date} {Time} Server      System Manufacturer: {Manufacturer}, System Model: {Model}.
{Date} {Time} Server      Authentication mode is MIXED.
{Date} {Time} Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\error.log'.
{Date} {Time} Server      The service account is '{domain}\{user}'. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
{Date} {Time} Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
     -c
     -S "MSSQL12E.LOCALDB"
     -s "LOCALDB#6A0C87E6"
     -d "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\master.mdf"
     -l "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\mastlog.ldf"
     -e "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\error.log"
{Date} {Time} Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 4 cores per socket and 4 logical processors per socket, 4 total logical processors; using 4 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
{Date} {Time} Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
{Date} {Time} Server      Detected 7113 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
{Date} {Time} Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
{Date} {Time} Server      Default collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (us_english 1033)
{Date} {Time} Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
{Date} {Time} Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0 Active CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
{Date} {Time} Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
{Date} {Time} Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
{Date} {Time} spid8s      Starting up database 'master'.
{Date} {Time} spid8s      24 transactions rolled forward in database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
{Date} {Time} spid8s      0 transactions rolled back in database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
{Date} {Time} Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
{Date} {Time} Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\.
{Date} {Time} spid8s      SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
{Date} {Time} spid8s      SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
{Date} {Time} spid8s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
{Date} {Time} spid8s      Server name is '{ComputerName}\LOCALDB#6A0C87E6'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
{Date} {Time} spid14s     Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\LOCALDB#6A0C87E6\tsql\query ].
{Date} {Time} spid14s     Dedicated administrator connection support was not started because it is disabled on this edition of SQL Server. If you want to use a dedicated administrator connection, restart SQL Server using the trace flag 7806. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
{Date} {Time} spid8s      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
{Date} {Time} spid8s      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBData.mdf for file number 0.  OS error: 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
{Date} {Time} spid8s      Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
{Date} {Time} spid8s      Unable to open the physical file "E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBData.mdf". Operating system error 3: "3(The system cannot find the path specified.)".
{Date} {Time} spid12s     Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
{Date} {Time} spid12s     The resource database build version is 12.00.4100. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
{Date} {Time} spid12s     Starting up database 'model'.
{Date} {Time} spid12s     Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
{Date} {Time} spid12s     FCB::Open failed: Could not open file E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\model.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
{Date} {Time} spid12s     Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
{Date} {Time} spid12s     Unable to open the physical file "E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\model.mdf". Operating system error 3: "3(The system cannot find the path specified.)".
{Date} {Time} spid12s     Error: 17207, Severity: 16, State: 1.
{Date} {Time} spid12s     FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file 'E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\modellog.ldf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.
{Date} {Time} spid12s     File activation failure. The physical file name "E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\modellog.ldf" may be incorrect.
{Date} {Time} spid12s     Error: 945, Severity: 14, State: 2.
{Date} {Time} spid12s     Database 'model' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory or disk space.  See the SQL Server errorlog for details.
{Date} {Time} spid12s     SQL Server shutdown has been initiated
{Date} {Time} spid12s     SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

Please note; I do not, nor have I ever had an `E:\` drive :\

Comment: You don't have an `E:` drive, ok, but does the rest of that long path `sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBData.mdf` make sense, just located at another drive letter?

Comment: Nope. The only thing in the entire path that makes any sense is the MSDBData.mdf - theres an mdf file of the same name at "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB" (which is where the log is located)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up deleting and recreating the instance.
I.E.

```
Open command prompt
-> cd %localappdata%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB
-> sqllocaldb delete mssqllocaldb
-> sqllocaldb create mssqllocaldb
-> sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb
```

Comment: I haven't actively installed the ReportViewer runtime, but I had the same issue with the v11.0 instance I had been running on my machine for quite some time. Recreating also fixed the issues for me.